# Why cookies are auto-set in node express js a response http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, setcookie

I'm developing a web app and there is already a login system that keep the session through a cookie. Now i would like to implement logout function. My idea was to delete cookie session but even if i clear cookies in every way when node express send back a response, cookies are auto-set.
I really don't know why. I'm using node express server with passport for login with Google, express-session, React for front end, axios for requests.

This is my request from Client:

```
const Logout = ({ login, setLogin}:Props ) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const _response = axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `http://127.0.0.1:3002/auth/logout`,
            withCredentials: true,

        }).then(res => {
            if(res.data === 'ok') setLogin(false)
            console.log(res.headers['session']);
            // window.location.replace('/projects')
        })

    }, [])
    return (<></>);
}
```

And this is how i get response from Server:

```
router.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
    res.clearCookie('session')
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'ppp')
    res.cookie('Set-Cookie', 'ZZZ', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true })
    res.send('ok')
});
```

As you can see below on the response headers i have multiple cookies 'Set-Cookie', but the last one is being inserted by default (?), and i don't know by who and why.

I tried to send different request with axios and fetch methods, changing GET with POST and so on but anything.

Having a cookie session it doesnt let me to effectively log-out. I think the solution is to delete that cookie so i can log with another gmail account. If there are better solution please let me know.

Thanks for everyone who can help me!

**General:**
URL di richiesta: http://127.0.0.1:3002/auth/logout
Metodo di richiesta: GET
Codice di stato: 200 OK
Indirizzo remoto: 127.0.0.1:3002
Criterio relativo al referrer: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 08:51:14 GMT
ETag: W/"2-eoX0dku9ba8cNUXvu/DyeabcC+s"
Set-Cookie: ppp
Set-Cookie: Set-Cookie=ZZZ; Max-Age=900; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 20 Feb
2023 09:06:14 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:
session=s%3AVtFyrI9jABANw_5oY09xDlYulRwJZaT1.aaJWZJeCHRDU6XGgJMu7Zgs1axAIdVYMurucpvKnJ3c; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 20 Feb 2023 11:15:14 GMT; HttpOnly
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express

**Request headers**:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:3002
If-None-Match: W/"2-eoX0dku9ba8cNUXvu/DyeabcC+s"
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Comment: Hey I think you may have forgotten to attach the image :)

Comment: You're right, i can't yet attach image! added request/response info as text, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second Set-Cookie header in your response:

> Set-Cookie=ZZZ; Max-Age=900; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 20 Feb 2023 09:06:14
> GMT; HttpOnly

Has the cookie name as Set-Cookie instead of a valid cookie name. This is causing the client to treat it as a new cookie, and therefore adding a third Set-Cookie header for the session cookie.

And why do you do that :

```
 res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'ppp')
```

It should be someting like that :

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'name=value')
```

You can, to clean that, replace :

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'ppp')
    res.cookie('Set-Cookie', 'ZZZ', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true })
```

By

```
res.cookie('ppp', 'cookieValue');
res.cookie('ZZZ', '{ maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true }');
```

Comment: even if i remove every 'manual' set cookie the last one will be added any way...

Comment: Please note that i don't want to create any new cookie. I tried to 'edit' the Set-Cookie in response headers changing the maxAge so it can expire when i log out. But i think that res.send('ok') is creating a new cookie (this one: Set-Cookie: session=s%3AVtFyrI9jABANw_5oY09xDlYulRwJZaT1.aaJWZJeCHRDU6XGgJMu7Zgs1axAIdVYMurucpvKnJ3c; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 20 Feb 2023 11:15:14 GMT; HttpOnly )